# How do i execute alert() in parent component after onClick in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In here, i'm passing data from child to parent and i am able to pass it through but i want alert function to execute only after onClick event is triggered in the child component but it is executing everytime onSubmit event is fired, it looks like there is a requirement of some life cycle method in order to make it work but i'm not getting it. Can someone help me with this please

## Parent

```
onList(list) {
  alert(list);
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <form>
        <input type='textarea'
               onKeyPress={this.handleSubmit}   
        />
        <Child {...this.state} sendList={this.onList}/>
       </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

## Child

```
    {
      this.props.listArr.map((list,index) => {
         return(
           <div key={index}>
            <li>{list}
              <div>
               <button className="btn btn-primary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" onClick={this.props.sendList(list)} />
              </div>
            </li>
           </div>
         )})
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

change to: 
`<Child {...this.state} sendList={(...args) => this.onList(...args)} />`, to preserve the function context.

then, in `Child` just call that method as `this.props.sendList()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` on button click so the form doesn't get submitted.

```js
const Child = ({ sendList, list }) => 
  <div>
    <button onClick={(event) => sendList(event, list)}>Click</button>
  </div>

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.onList = this.onList.bind(this)
  }

  onList(event, list) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('onList', list)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>    
        <Child sendList={this.onList} list={[]} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```